# How to use ORM methods on save button click?

Tags: python, xml, odoo-8, odoo

i have done ORM methods worked out only when some action buttons defined in xml file. but i want to know how to do the same when the SAVE button clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the "Save" button the `create` method of the model is executed. Is that what you are looking for?

If you want to run a specific method of the model, write the name of the method in the attribute `name` of the button. The type of the button should be `object`:

```
<button name="method_name" type="object" string="Example" class="oe_highlight" />
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answer but.. i don't want add ACTION buttons in anywhere in form view.. i want to run any method when save button clicked. i know save button executes create method. Could you please help with this...

Comment: You can override the create method. Execute the parent create in order to run both methods